# Scroll button for gradual scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to create a Scroll Down Button that scrolls down at a settable speed while the scroll button is in click down position, or on tablets in touch position. At the bottom of the page the Scroll Down Button should become a Scroll To Top Button. Not being lazy, I have searched for this but I could find all sorts of scroll methods but not this one. Can anyone please help. Some code to get things started (I hope). [**JSFIDDLE HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fyrrqw7x/4/)

```css
#scrollButtonDown{
 position:fixed;
 width:80px;
 height:80px;
 border-radius:40px;
 bottom:0;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 color:#ffffff;
 text-align:center;
 }
 
 
 #scrollButtonTop{
 position:fixed;
 width:80px;
 height:80px;
 border-radius:40px;
 bottom:0;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 color:#ffffff;
 text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
What is Lorem Ipsum?<br>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
<br><br>
Why do we use it?<br>
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
<br><br>
Where does it come from?<br>
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
<br><br>
The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
<br><br>
Where can I get some?<br>
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
<br><br>
What is Lorem Ipsum?<br>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
<br><br>
Why do we use it?<br>
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
<br><br>
Where does it come from?<br>
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
<br><br>
The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
<br><br>
Where can I get some?<br>
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.

<button id="scrollButtonDown" class="glyphicon glyphiconwchevron-down">SCROLL DOWN</button>
<button id="scrollButtonTop" class="glyphicon glyphiconwchevron-up">SCROLL TOP</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event handlers to change the state of a "scrolling" variable. and have a `setInterval` running to watch for that variable to become true.
You can change the speed by either changing the interval time, or the amount the page is moved per interval

```
var scrolling = false;
var atBottom = false;

window.onload = function(){
  var eButton = document.getElementById("scrollButtonTop");
  eButton.addEventListener("mousedown", bDown);
  eButton.addEventListener("mouseup", bUp);
  eButton.addEventListener("mouseout", bUp);
  eButton.addEventListener("touchstart", bDown);
  eButton.addEventListener("touchend", bUp);
}
window.onscroll = function(){
  var eButton = document.getElementById("scrollButtonTop");
  var scrollPos = window.pageYOffset ||
                  document.documentElement.scrollTop || 
                  document.body.scrollTop || 
                  0;
  if(scrollPos + window.innerHeight > document.body.clientHeight - 10){
    atBottom = true;
    eButton.innerHTML = "GO&thinsp;TO<br>TOP";
    eButton.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up";
  } else {
    atBottom = false;
    eButton.innerHTML = "SCROLL<br>DOWN";
    eButton.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down";
  }
}
function bDown(){
  if(atBottom) window.scrollTo(0,0);
  else scrolling = true;
}
function bUp(){
  scrolling = false;
}

setInterval(function(){
  if(scrolling) window.scrollBy(0,1);
},50);
```

[JSfiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cb0pa8h9/8/)

Comment: Thank you, Tyler! May I ask you please to create a demo. I am adding your code but it is not working here.

Comment: @Eddy - woopsies.. I don't know where I thought of "addEventHandler" , I've updated my code to include actual javascript. hah. let me know if it works better now.

Comment: @Eddy - Thanks, I was on a roll, so you get a bonus. I added in the "scroll up" functionality also. You're welcome.

Comment: and thanks again, Tyler! It works but.., when I scroll to the bottom of the page at the current speed as you have set, and by using the button all is good. But if I set the speed faster, or use the scrollbar instead, the button does not change at the page bottom.

Comment: I also added some changes to your code in the "function bUp(){" section. One of the changes being, changing the classname when the bottom of the page is reached. But how do I get it to change the classname back to "glyphicon glyphiconwchevron-down" when the page is it not at the bottom?

Comment: any help would be very much appreciated, Tyler

Comment: Also your code for changing the button to Go To Top does not seem to work in Firefox.

Comment: One more thing (and my apologies that it's now becoming a few things), when the click down is released outside of the button the scroll continues. Is there a way to stop the scroll, even if the click down is released outside of the button?

Comment: @Eddy - the button wouldn't change from manual scrolling because it only changes after a click. And my not change from a faster speed if it doesn't land exactly at the bottom of the page, 1px off or something. we could fix that by moving the last 3 lines of bUp() into `window.onscroll` function so that if updates the button during manual scroll, and changing the calculation to `document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight > document.body.clientHeight - 10` so the button changes if we're even just close to the bottom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128628/discussion-between-tyler-mackenzie-and-eddy).